# Socket in java and nmap

Tags: java, sockets, networking, nmap

I have program write it in java it's wait a connection on port

when I scan the server by nmap the program  is stop (erorr)

this is my code

```
SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
                sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket)sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(intSSLport);

out = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslSocket.getInputStream()));
                  String value = in.readLine();
```

thanks jtahlborn ,,,, I solved by using try and catch ,,, and make catch return to

```
sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sslServerSocket.accept()
```

again

Comment: @MohamedAlharbi are you sure it's not just blocking, waiting indefinitely for input? Try setting a socket timeout.

Comment: @dimba is correct, probably your program is waiting for a response which will not arrive since Nmap will just quit after it recognizes port as open. A socket timeout as oldrinb suggested may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

nmap is scanning open ports, by trying to connect to them (sending TCP SYN). 
Since you've opened server socket, it returns when there's a client connecting to it.
In your case it's nmap, which tries to connect.

AFAIK, nmap won't complete TCP connection procedure (3 way handshake). nmap will receive TCP SYN/ACK sent as result of your call to accept(), and will conclude the port is open. 
That it's all, nmap won't send 3rd message required to complete TCP connection procedure (ACK).